# Why is "томат" spelt without an "o" at the end?

Tags: этимология, правописание, заимствования

I'm trying to understand how spelling works in Russian. Why does "томат" lack an "o" at the end, when some other words which I assume are derived from European loanwords, such as "пианино" or "метро", have an "о" at the end?

The English [edition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82) of Wiktionary lacked etymology info for "томат".

Comment: what makes you believe it should end with -о when it was borrowed not from Spanish?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why on Earth it should be? Just because in other languages -ato ending are OK for nouns? Why `банан` and not `банана`? Or `кофе` but not `кофи`?

This is emotional part of an answer, and as of the facts - well, it was derived from French `tomate` (which is something mentioned in [Russian wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82) by the way)  and in French it was already pronounced pretty much the same way.

I guess the main question is why we are not pronouncing it like `томатль` - after all it was originally that way )))

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm how come? It was borrowed from French where it was pronounced exactly this way, пианио and метро were borrowed from word that were ended at -о.

Comment: Кофе matches at least the spelling in French, if not the pronunciation.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm well `tomate`, just like I've said is pronounced without -o - and that's the reason why when it was borrower from French there was no -о as well. So I still insist-  how this does not answer the question? You've asked about the origin of this word in Russian and here it is.

Comment: My comment referred to the original version of the answer, not the current one.

Comment: "Томатль" is the thing that makes me love Russian.SE

Comment: I could swear that the original version of this answer didn't mention French etymology. Either my memory is wrong, or it was added in in the first five minutes of posting the answer.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm `Кофе matches at least the spelling in French, if not the pronunciation` Кофе is a difficult compromise between Dutch (originally it was Кофий in Russian) and French.

Answer (score 5):

Words get borrowed into the languages not necessarily from the languages they originated in, not necessarily keeping their meaning, not necessarily the way they originally sounded and not necessarily once.

In each separate case there is usually some kind of logic: e.g. you can trace step by step how Ancient Greek *ἐλέφας* (source of English "elephant") ultimately became Russian *верблюд* ("camel"), or how *гиацинт* and *яхонт* are both from a common Greek source, but it's an ad-hoc logic every time.

As for *томат, банан* etc., they were borrowed from French where they are pronounced in almost the same way as they are in Russian, and *батат* is most probably from Neapolitan or other southern Italian idiom.

Words borrowed from Spanish either directly or through English (*торнадо, авокадо* etc.) are neuter and indeclinable, and keep the final *-о*.